# Mutate Nested Dictionary With Paths

Tags: swift

I have a dictionary of `[String : Any]` and I need to mutate some values at unknown positions in the dictionary. They are given by a list of paths passed into the method. If I had the keys already it would look something like: `dic["key1"]["key2"] = ["val":1]`. What is the best way to accomplish this?

This code is meant to mutate a dictionary of preferences for the user, and was originally written in obj-C, where dictionaries are pass by references. Basically, these are like JSON nodes, hence the `Any` instead of something more strongly typed.

Here is the code I'm trying to convert, which I did not write:

```
- (void)setRelativePath:(NSString *)path add:(BOOL)add {
NSMutableArray *pathComponents = [[[self fullPath:path] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] mutableCopy];
if ([pathComponents count]) {
    if ([pathComponents count] > 1) {
        NSString *rootKey = pathComponents[0];
        [pathComponents removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        NSMutableDictionary *rootDictionary = [[self.cacheGetter() dictionaryForKey:rootKey] mutableCopy];
        if (!rootDictionary) {
            rootDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        }
        NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = rootDictionary;
        while ([pathComponents count] > 1) {
            NSString *nextKey = pathComponents[0];
            NSDictionary *current = dictionary[nextKey];
            [pathComponents removeObjectAtIndex:0];
            NSMutableDictionary *next = current ? [current mutableCopy] : [NSMutableDictionary new];
            dictionary[nextKey] = next;
            dictionary = next;
        }
        if (add) {
            dictionary[pathComponents[0]] = @(YES);
        } else {
            [dictionary removeObjectForKey:pathComponents[0]];
        }
        [self.cacheGetter() setValue:rootDictionary forKey:rootKey];
    } else if (add) {
        [self.cacheGetter() setBool:YES forKey:path];
    } else {
        [self.cacheGetter() removeObjectForKey:path];
    }
    [self.cacheGetter() synchronize];
}
}
```

Comment: Wait, are you saying you want the value for `key2` to be `1` or you want the value for `key2` to be an even deeper nested dictionary `["val":1]`?

Comment: Another question to ask yourself is why you are in this predicament. Any time you find yourself using Any, that's a Bad Smell. Swift doesn't like that sort of thing. It might be better to describe to us what's _really_ going on so we can suggest a better overall strategy.

Comment: @matt I added some clarification, maybe that helps.

Comment: If these are JSON nodes, your best bet is the create structs/classes that represent them, decode the JSON and encode when needed. Then your updates will be much easier.

Comment: @Sulthan That's what I'm thinking, because I can't think of another way to do it, but I thought I would ask in case I'm missing something.

Comment: Well I suppose you _could_ just go right on using NSMutableDictionary in Swift. Or you could even leave that method in Objective-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this dynamically is to keep on using `NSMutableDictionary` in Swift. It does not appear there is a good way to do this with Swift dictionaries, besides creating structs/classes to represent the actual keys, instead of doing it dynamically. Thanks matt and Sulthan.